# collecting Sample points on the oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I am using a 1.5GHz bandwidth and 20GSamples/sec oscilloscope to measure a signal. The measurement is TDR(Time Domain Refelctometry)

I would like to collect the raw data from the oscilloscope. How can I do it?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: This probably depends on the oscilloscope. What are you using?

Comment: Teledyne Lecroy WavePro 715Zi-A

1.5 GHz, 10 GS/s, 4ch, 20 Mpts/Ch DSO   50 ohm and 1 Mohm Input. 20 GS/s and 40 Mpts/Ch in interleaved mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Lecroy WaveMaster it's just file->save waveform.   Then choose file instead of memory option and it will open up a menu showing options for format like binary, excel, matlab, etc.